# Can I use a static IP address to ensure that I have uninterrupted connection to a cloud software?

Tags: networking, router, static-ip

Forgive me for whatever blunders I'm about to make in asking networking questions.

Basically, I want to have an uninterrupted connection to a property management system that is on the cloud. As a hotelier, I want to use a cloud software to manage my business. I would use the software to allow my customers to make reservations online, to manage visitor and guest traffic, and etc.

Problem is, internet connection is not always reliable in my country. So I've read about static IP addresses and thought it could a viable solution to my problem.

I've read that static IPs can be used to host local web servers. But since I am connecting to a cloud, will I be able to us a static IP for that function?

Or will I be better off running my own web server, like hosting my own web site, have my website connect to the cloud?

Or I am getting the concept of static IPs all wrong? Forgive the naivete.

Comment: Is your computer connected to a home router? Does your ISP provide static IP?

Comment: "Or I am getting the concept of static IPs all wrong" - Yes; Yes you are.  Even with a dynamic ip address you can have 24/7 internet connection.  A static ip address will not help with an unreliable internet connection.  "Or will I be better off running my own web server, like hosting my own web site, have my website connect to the cloud?: ` This won't solve your problem either.

Comment: @Biswa Yes, my ISP provides for static IP. The connection will be for a business establishment

Comment: @Ramhound So there is no way to solve unreliable internet connection?

Comment: @user2999013 To make the connection more reliable, change the ISP or the connection to ISP. On the whole the TCP/IP protocol is fairly resilient to short outages.

Comment: @user2999013 Determine if the reliability problem is something that your ISP can solve

Answer (score 0):

If you run the server locally in your hotel, then it has the IP that your ISP provides, and having a static IP for this is best, because your clients will want to use youhotel.com to connect to the site and this has to be converted to an IP and it's a lot simpler when this IP is static.

When your server is in the cloud, then its IP is static and you don't have to worry about such things.

And when your server is in the cloud, the IP **you** use to access it isn't really important (at best it should not change during a session, but normally servers don't really care about this).  The only benefit of you having a static IP in that case is that the IP could be used to refine(*) the access control (for instance only allowing admin access from your IP). But it may not be worth the trouble.

(*) "refine" because it shouldn't be the only criterion.

Comment: So static IPs have no impact on internet reliability?

Comment: A cloud server will already have a static IP, or how will you yourself connect to it? But this has no effect on speed.

Comment: @user2999013 No effect et whatsoever.